# Create a non-overlay modal that does non closable where user can still navigate on background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, modal-dialog

Hello I want to know how to create a modal that doesn't overlay, it means that the user can still navigate with that container still showing there, it can be moved , minimized or keep it still there, and also it won't close even if the user clicks the background. I tried to do some research but I can't seem to find the right answer because it is always bootstrap that I see.

This is what I want.
[image]

thanks in advance for helping!.

Comment: In Chrome the only solution for such always-on-top modal is to add it into the web page as an element (usually `iframe` that points to an html file inside the extension, declared in web_accessible_resources).

Comment: Not a very user friendly design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use JQuery UI Dialog, for example:

```css
.ui-dialog{
  bottom: 0px;
  top: auto !important;
  left: auto !important;
  right:0px;
  position: fixed !important;
}
body{
  background: red;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

To close the Modal, you have to use the method close; see the documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Not applicable because the UI must be shown on any web page not controlled by the OP. This task is specific to extensions.